# What are some things to keep in mind when searching for a step motor where a lot of torque is required?

Tags: stepper-motor

I want to build rotating arms of length around 2ft that can hold up to 30 lbs of weight and am wondering what kind of motor to get. I'm thinking of getting a step motor so that I can know exactly which angle the arm is at.

The key requirement is that it needs to be a high torque delivering system. Gears would be good to achieve this but as a beginner, I don't have a lot of experience with constructing my own gear-motor combinations.

Comment: Have you searched this topic on here? There are several existing similar questions...

Comment: You may also want to be aware that stepper motors unless equipped with encoders will not give you position feedback. You would have to add an encoder or use a more expensive servo rated for the loads you reference.

Comment: This is not a good application for a stepper motor.  You probably want a gearmotor with an encoder to close a servo loop, though getting it to not oscillate across geartrain backlash can be tricky.   You could put the encoder at the motor upstream of the gears and just accept a small load- and last direction-
 dependent position uncertainty.  You can also look at screw jacks (where a stepper might be workable) or hydraulics.